# How to use unit of work in rest controller properly?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, unit-of-work

```
public interface CourseRepo extends CrudRepository<Course, Long> {

}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor 
 public class UnitOfWork {

    CourseRepo courses;
    StudentRepository students;
    StudyProgramRepository studyPrograms;
    StudySchemeRepo studySchemes;
    FeeStructureRepository feeStructures;
}
```

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    
    @Autowired
    UnitOfWork uow;
    

    @GetMapping("/addcr")
    public String addCourse() {
        
        Course cr = new Course();
        cr.setTitle("DingDong course");
        uow.getCourses().save(cr);

        return "course Added..!!" ;
    }
```

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field uow in com.srs.TestController required a bean of type 'com.srs.uow.UnitOfWork' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.srs.uow.UnitOfWork' in your configuration.
```

if i remove autowired and add a bean

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    
    @Bean
    public UnitOfWork uow() {
        return new UnitOfWork();
    }

    @GetMapping("/addcr")
    public String addCourse() {
        
        Course cr = new Course();
        cr.setTitle("DingDong course");
        uow().getCourses().save(cr);

        return "course Added..!!" ;
    }
```

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.srs.jpa.CourseRepo.save(Object)"
because the return value of "com.srs.uow.UnitOfWork.getCourses()" is null

i tried both autowired and in this case how can i use autowired or bean properly ?

Comment: Add "@Component" annotation to UnitOfWork. Moreover you can replace the for lombok annotation with the @Data annotation (it a shortcut that enable the 4 annotations you added).

Comment: yes it worked . thanks a lot for your time :) i love stack over flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class need to be annotated with @Component to be used with DI provider by @Autowired annotation

For the same reason each repository of your class need to be annotated with @Autowired

Answer (score 0):

The Error Message gives the answer.

> Field uow in com.srs.TestController required a bean of type 'com.srs.uow.UnitOfWork' that could not be found.

spring is searching for a bean from type UnitOfWork. You have to add this class to the application context from spring boot. To accomplish this you have to annotate the class UnitOfWork with **@bean** or **@Data** if you use lombok.
After this the spring application can find the Class UnitOfWork and auto wire it.

Answer (score 0):

Since UnitOfWork (a somewhat misleading name in the JPA context) autowires data repositories, it has to be a Spring Bean itself.

The easiest and most common way is to annotate the class with one of the annotations `@Service`, `@Component` or `@Bean`, depending on the semantic of the class. There are also other ways, like the `@Bean` on method-level as you used.

To use the fully initialized bean you need to autowire it where you want to use it, not calling the create method. E.g. calling `uow()` as in your sample, bypasses the Spring Bean mechanism and creates a new instance, which hasn't been fully initialized (thus the NullPointerException).

Usually, the beans are autowired as fields, sometimes they are autowired in mehtod parameters (especially when working with @Bean on method-level in the same class).

E.g.

```
 @Component
 @Getter
 @RequiredArgsConstructor 
 public class UnitOfWork {

    private final CourseRepo courses;
    private final StudentRepository students;
    private final StudyProgramRepository studyPrograms;
    private final StudySchemeRepo studySchemes;
    private final FeeStructureRepository feeStructures;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed answer. concept is clear now.